# How to update PyTorch model parameters (tensors) after averaging them?

Tags: pytorch

I'm currently working on a distributed federated learning infrastructure and am trying to implement PyTorch. For this I also need federated averaging which averages the retrieved parameters from all the nodes and then passes those to a next training round.

The gathering of the parameters looks like this:

```
def RPC_get_parameters(data, model):
    """
    Get parameters from nodes
    """

    with torch.no_grad():
        for parameters in model.parameters():
            # store parameters in dict
            return {"parameters": parameters}
```

The averaging function which happens at the central server looks like this:

```
# stores results from RPC_get_parameters() in results

results = client.get_results(task_id=task.get("id"))

# averaging of returned parameters
global_sum = 0
global_count = 0
    
for output in results:
    global_sum += output["parameters"]
    global_count += len(global_sum)
    #
    averaged_parameters = global_sum/global_count
    #
    new_params = {'averaged_parameters': averaged_parameters}
```

Now my question is, how do you update all the parameters (tensors) in Pytorch from this? I tried a few things and they usually returned errors like "Value Error: can't optimize a non-leaf tensor" when inserting new_params into the optimizer where usually model.parameters() go optimizerD = optim.SGD(new_params, lr=0.01, momentum = 0.5). So how do I actually update the model so it uses the averaged parameters?

Thank you!

https://github.com/simontkl/torch-vantage6/blob/fed_avg-w/local_dp/v6-ppsdg-py/master.py

Answer (score 0):

I think the most convenient way to work with parameters (outside the SGD context) is using the [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) of the model.

```py
new_params = OrderedDict()

n = len(clients)  # number of clients

for client_model in clients:
  sd = client_model.state_dict()  # get current parameters of one client
  for k, v in sd.items():
    new_params[k] = new_params.get(k, 0) + v / n
```

After that `new_params` is a `state_dict` (you can load it using [`.load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict)) with the average weights of the clients.

Comment: Thank you! client_model is the trained model of a client, right? And client is I assume one of the nodes (in my project called organizations). Hence, client = organization. In the infrastructure I use (vantage6), the organizations are merely a dictionary of participating orgs/nodes. So len(organizations) would work for the averaging, but I cannot simply take the model from the organization. Everything is sent to the nodes/orgs and the model is returned. Therefore "for client_model in organizations:" gives me the error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'state_dict'. I added my git

Comment: @SimonTokloth so ask organization to send the state_dict of their model